# How do I combine these two functions into a single function that takes two parameters?

Tags: react-native, this, bind

I have two functions:

```
setCallModalFalse = (incomingFlag) => () => {
        if (incomingFlag === 'EmergencyCall') {
            this.setState({ callModal: false });
            this.props.navigation.navigate('EmergencyCall'); 
        } else {
            loggingService.debug('we are not going anywhere');
            this.setState({ callModal: false });
        }
    }
setBeepModalFalse = (incomingFlag) => () => {
            if (incomingFlag === 'PoliceIconPage') {
                this.setState({ beepModal: false });
                this.props.navigation.navigate('PoliceIconPage');
            } else {
                loggingService.debug('hey you pressed setbeepmodalfalse');
                this.setState({ beepModal: false });
            }
```

I'm trying to combine them into a single function

```
handleModalAndNavigation = (whichModal, incomingFlag) => () => {
    if (whichModal === 'beep' && incomingFlag === 'PoliceIconPage') {
        this.setState({ beepModal: false });
        this.props.navigation.navigate('PoliceIconPage'); 
    } else {
        this.setState({ beepModal: false });
    }
    if (whichModal === 'call' && incomingFlag === 'EmergencyCall') {
        this.setState({ callModal: false });
        this.props.navigation.navigate('EmergencyCall'); 
    } else {
        this.setState({ callModal: false });
    }
}
```

my constructor looks like this:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.setBeepModalFalse = this.setBeepModalFalse.bind(this);
        this.setCallModalFalse = this.setCallModalFalse.bind(this);
        this.callButton = this.callButton.bind(this);
        this.alarmButton = this.alarmButton.bind(this);
        this.handleModalAndNavigation = this.handleModalAndNavigation.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            callModal: false,
            beepModal: false,

        };
        this.batteryLevelIndicator = '';
    }
```

However, when I try to load this, I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined'"

There aren't any issues when I use setCallModalFalse and setBeepModalFalse.
Why is my function suddenly undefined?

Comment: Be sure that you don't have any typos. Since you are using arrow functions it is unnecessary to bind them. You don't need to do bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove bind function declaration `//this.handleModalAndNavigation = this.handleModalAndNavigation.bind(this);` in constructor because you have already use ES6 syntax while declaring functions.

and your function declaration should be something look like this,

```
handleModalAndNavigation = (whichModal, incomingFlag) => {
    if (whichModal === 'beep' && incomingFlag === 'PoliceIconPage') {
        this.setState({ beepModal: false });
        this.props.navigation.navigate('PoliceIconPage'); 
    } else {
        this.setState({ beepModal: false });
    }

    if (whichModal === 'call' && incomingFlag === 'EmergencyCall') {
        this.setState({ callModal: false });
        this.props.navigation.navigate('EmergencyCall'); 
    } else {
        this.setState({ callModal: false });
    }
}
```